# Block variation / Variation API scope "transform"

Tags: block-editor

I have a simple Block Variation for core/heading -

```
    wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
    'core/heading',
    [{
        name: 'my heading',
        title: 'My Heading',
        attributes: {
            level: 3,
            className: 'is-style-my-heading',
        },
        scope: [ 'inserter', 'transform' ],
    }]
);
```

It works in the inserter, but I can't make the variation visible in the transforms component for some reason. But maybe I don't sufficiently understand what the 'transform' in the scope attribute is supposed to do. I can transform the block variation to, say, a paragraph (not the core version of heading for some reason), but when I try to transform the paragraph the list of available transforms only gives the core/heading block, not the variation.

So if I'd like to transform a core/heading or a core/paragraph to my-heading (with specified level) then it seems all I can do now is copy the content, delete core block, insert the variation block and paste the content back in.

Is this the only way? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: the documentation says the defaults are `block` and `inserter`, is there a reason you chose not to add `block`? Note that variations are not blocks, your variation is and always will be a `core/heading` block, much in the same way that all embeds are `core/embed` blocks, even though the different variants have different icons and URLs, and possibly differing attribute values, they are all still a `core/embed` block

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I also tried with 'block', didn't make a difference. As I understand 'block" refers to the block variation picker within blocks, like core/columns, so I assumed this wouldn't help me in this case.

Comment: and are you using WP 5.9+?

Comment: Yes, I am on 5.9.2 (with Gutenberg plugin active)

Comment: Okay, so far I've overlooked a transform menu in the sidebar that allows to transform a heading to the variation, so I apparently didn't understand that the 'transform' scope wouldn't allow to pick the variation from the transform component, but enable its proper UI in the sidebar. It still seems convoluted to have to first choose a core/heading before being able to transform it into the variation, but at least it's possible. Thanks for your help!